# CSS mask pseudo element by parent div?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm using a psuedo element to fade a gradient over another div which has an image as a background for that div.

My html layout is like so:

```
<div class='portfolio_thumb'>
    <div class='portfolio_thumb_caption'></div
</div
```

and my CSS for those items

```
.portfolio_thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
}

    .portfolio_thumb .portfolio_thumb_caption:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(72,76,97,0) 0%, rgba(72,76,97,0.8) 75%);
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
    }

    .portfolio_thumb:hover .portfolio_thumb_caption:before {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Right now the gradient fades in and starts to slide, but it is shown past the parent div. I only want the gradient shown within the bounds of the portfolio_thumb div. Also, both divs in that html snippet are the same heights. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm going for this kind of approach. http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/

Thanks!

Comment: Preferably make your demo in CodePen or elsewhere so people can examine it properly.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `overflow: hidden` on the container to cut-off the gradient.
- Use `transform: translateY(x%)` to move the gradient up and down. As we are not creating 3d animations, there is no point using `translate3d`, which requires more grunt to run.
- The `transition` smoothly shows and hides the overlay

### Complete Example

```css
.portfolio_thumb {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-300-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 840px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.portfolio_thumb .portfolio_thumb_caption:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(72, 76, 97, 0) 0%, rgba(72, 76, 97, 0.8) 75%);
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  opacity: 0;
}
.portfolio_thumb:hover .portfolio_thumb_caption:before {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='portfolio_thumb'>
  <div class='portfolio_thumb_caption'></div>
</div>
```